# Java Apache-poi, memory leak with excel files

Tags: java, excel, memory-leaks, apache-poi

I need to read (15000) excel files for my thesis. I'm using apache poi to open and later to analyze them but after around 5000 files I'm getting the following exception and stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3044)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3065)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxHandler.startElement(Locale.java:3263)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportStartTag(Piccolo.java:1082)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseAttributesNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1822)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseOpenTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1521)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1362)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:4682)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3479)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1277)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1264)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:92)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:173)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:165)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:417)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:382)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:178)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:249)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:302)
at de.spreadsheet_realtions.analysis.WorkbookAnalysis.analyze(WorkbookAnalysis.java:18)
```

**Code** (at the moment just open the file and close the file):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    start();
}

public void start(){
    File[] files = getAllFiles(Config.folder);
    ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0.00);
    for(File f: files){
        analyze(f);
    }
}

public void analyze(File file){
    Workbook  workbook = null;
    try {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); //line 18
    } catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace(); return;}
//      later would be here the code to analyze the workbook
    try {
        workbook.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

I tried also with OPCPackage.open(file) and I got the same result.

What I'm doing wrong or what can I do to solve this problem? Thanks for any help.

---

EDIT:
The same for the code below.

```
try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file)){
} catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace(); return;}
```

Comment: It could be one very big file that causes an OOM based on the memory settings that you define for you java process. Can you try to run only with the one file where the OOM happens and see if this one alone already triggers the OOM?

Comment: Yes, it is one big file (42mb) and whiteout this file it is working :-) thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, POI has the whole workbook in memory. So, a large workbook requires a different approach.

While *writing*, one can use [SXSSF](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) and most calls are the same, except that only a certain number of rows are in memory.

In your case, you are *reading*. For this you can use their "event driven" API. The basic idea here is that you do not get the workbook as one huge object. Instead, you get it piecemeal, as it is read, and you can save off as much as you wish into your own data-structure. Or, you can simply process it as you read it and not save very much.

Since this is a lower-level API (driven by the structure of the data being read), there is one approach for XLS and a different approach for XLSX. Look at the POI ["How To" page](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api), and find the section titled "XSSF and SAX (Event API)".

That example demonstrates how to detect the value of each cell as it is read in.
(You'll need the xercesImpl.jar on your library path.)

Answer (score 2):

In the case of an exception in your first try block, you return, so you wouldn't close the workbook.

Put the close in a `finally` block.

```
Workbook workbook = null;
try {
  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); //line 18

  // later would be here the code to analyze the workbook
} catch (Exception e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace(); return;
}  finally {
  if (workbook != null) workbook.close();
}
```

Or, better, use try-with-resources.

```
try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file) {
  // later would be here the code to analyze
} catch (Exception e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
// No need for explicit close.
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried it but I get the same exception and stacktrace after the same number of files.

Comment: Well, in that case it's not an issue with the code you posted :) You are probably holding on to references to stuff inside the code you are using to analyze the workbook - OOM failures don't necessarily manifest in the place where the actual memory leak is occurring.

Comment: That is the point which I don't understand because I only create a new xssfworkbook and close it. I'm doing nothing with the workbook at the moment. I added the complete code which I executing.