# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded Error while Reading Macro enabled excel sheet through Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, jsp, garbage-collection, apache-poi

I have a **Macro Enabled Excel file in XLSM format**. Inside this excel, 2-3 dependent dropdowns are there. I have written a macro code to stop delete for a particular column.

I am uploading this excel using the following code.

```html
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new 
            FileInputStream(fileName));
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
            XSSFRow row;
            XSSFCell cell;
            int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
```

But it is giving a ERROR:

```html
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject
    (DeferredDocumentImpl.java:972)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl.synchronizeD
    ata(DeferredElementNSImpl.java:126)
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.getNamespaceURI(Elem
    entNSImpl.java:250)
```

**While Uploading without macro, there is no error and working fine.**

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded : This error comes when GC is unable to freeup objects in continuous cycles. You can specify the limit in vm startup arguments.

This means with Macro on your references beocme strong and are not eligible for GC . The same objects in the absence of Macro are eligible for GC.

You need to look into as why on addding Macro , references are becoming reachable.

Comment: Then, what should I do now??

Comment: Since you are using macro to stop/delete a particular column you are keeping your objects reference strong. Getting GC Overhead in apache poi is a common error. Some solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389920/java-apache-poi-memory-leak-with-excel-files